# Batch loop each wave file in folder while total audio duration is less than 4 minutes

Tags: windows, audio, batch

I'm looking to edit many wave files in a folder by using a batch command as such: take one file and repeat it to the shortest duration greater than 4 minutes.

It doesn't matter what program could do it, as long as it's free and runs on Windows 10.

It doesn't matter whether or not it is command-line.

SoX won't do, as I can't afford to calculate the times required for all audio files (hundreds) to be repeated until the result exceeds 4 minutes.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

I made for you a beginning of a vbscript to get duration of all `.*wav` files greater or equal to 4 seconds from this folder `C:\Windows\Media`

and if you want to get greater or equal to 4 minutes just change this line

`If Split(oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,LENGTH),":")(2) >= 4 Then` by this one

`If Split(oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,LENGTH),":")(1) >= 4 Then`

Just give a try and tell me what you want to modify for your case :

```vbs
Const LENGTH = 27 
Dim oShell  : Set oShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace("C:\Windows\Media")
DIM oFSO    : Set oFSO    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each strFileName in oFolder.Items
If Lcase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName.Name)) = Lcase("wav") Then
    If Split(oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,LENGTH),":")(2) >= 4 Then
        Msg = Msg & "File name: " &_
        oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,FILE_NAME) &_
        vbTab & "Duration : "& oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,LENGTH) & vbcrlf
    End If
End If
Next
wscript.echo Msg
```

---

***EDIT :*** Adding another code in batch to generate the vbscript above and get the result into a text file :

```bat
@echo off
Title Get Duration from *.wav files using vbscript and Batch
Set "LogFile=%~dp0MusicLength.txt"
Call :Generate_VBS_File
Call :Execute_VBS_File
If exist "%LogFile%" Start "" /MAX "%LogFile%"
pause
EXIT
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Generate_VBS_File
>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ( 
    echo    Const LENGTH = 27 
    echo    Dim oShell  : Set oShell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application"^)
    echo    Dim oFolder : Set oFolder = oShell.Namespace("C:\Windows\Media"^)
    echo    DIM oFSO    : Set oFSO    = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    echo    For Each strFileName in oFolder.Items
    echo    If Lcase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(strFileName.Name^)^) = Lcase("wav"^) Then
    echo        If Split(oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,LENGTH^),":"^)(2^) ^>= 4 Then
    echo            Msg = Msg ^& "File name: " ^&_
    echo            oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,FILE_NAME^) ^&_
    echo            vbTab ^& "Duration : "^& oFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName,LENGTH^) ^& vbcrlf
    echo        End If
    echo    End If
    echo    Next
    echo    wscript.echo Msg
)
Exit /B
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Execute_VBS_File
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs">"%LogFile%"
If exist "%LogFile%" Type "%LogFile%"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem you understood my question. I meant iterate through each wave file. For each wave file, keep looping it until the total audio duration is greater than 4 minutes and export the result.

Comment: @antoniu200 Sorry i still didn't understand your request ?? What did you mean by itearte each wave file ? did you mean play it ? and what did you mean by export the result ? what result did you expect ? Please explain more your aim and edit your question with those additional informations that i asked for ! Thank you !